# Does "ad" have its origin in Hebrew/Semitic languages?

Tags: etymology, particle, hebrew

The sources I've read usually say that 'ad' (i.e., in 'ad infinitum') is derived from Proto-Indo-European `*ád` ‎("near, at"). However, they don't refer any Semitic origins.

But here's an excerpt from Philip Baldi's [Semitic Influence in the History of Latin Syntax](http://www.academia.edu/879382/Semitic_Influence_in_the_History_of_Latin_Syntax_in_New_Perspectives_on_Historical_Latin_Syntax_1_2009_):

> However, the Latin preposition *ad* here may correspond to the Semitic preposition *l*, which would constitute merely an isolated calque, rather than a true example of syntactic interference

<sup>(Semitic Influence in the History of Latin Syntax, 1.1, footnote 3)</sup>

So here's my question: Does 'ad' originate from the Hebrew 'ad' (to/towards) or a similar Semitic origin?

Comment: Elementary prepositions are rarely borrowed from another language.

Comment: That quotation does not say that latin *ad* originates from Semetic *I.* In fact, it implies that it does not. It says it might "correspond" to it in this one expression. A [*calque*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) is when an expression is translated "literally" from one language to another, resulting in a parallel formation. For example, French "gratte-ciel" literally "scrape-sky" is a calque of English "skyscraper."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, the similarity is almost certainly accidental. This kind of coincidental similarity is pretty common, especially in short words like *ad*.

Latin *ad* "to, near, at" has cognates in several other branches of Indo-European, including Celtic (Old Irish *ad-*), Phrygian (αδ-), and Germanic -- English *at* is among the latter. It appears to go back to a Proto-Indo-European form such as *h₂ed.

Hebrew *ʕad* "toward" appears to have originally had a temporal meaning, "until"; it's homonymous with a noun meaning "perpetuity". It's very unlikely that this word would have been borrowed as a preposition into Proto-Indo-European, both because languages rarely borrow prepositions and because there is not much evidence for contact between these two language families in the first place.